# getting a pojo from mongo doc

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I use morphia and mongodb.
I need to get a pojo from mongo doc.
The connection to the database works well.
I had a class which contains the database fields, getters and setters.

When i execute the following code:

```
public class TestCon extends HttpServlet{

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
                                   throws ServletException, IOException { 
      Morphia morphia=new Morphia();
      MongoClient  mongoClient = new MongoClient( "192.168.1.254" , 27017 );
      DB db = mongoClient.getDB( "syslog" );  
      Set<String> tables = db.getCollectionNames();
      for(String coll : tables){
          PrintWriter writer = res.getWriter();
          writer.println(coll);
      }

      BasicDBObject idObj=new BasicDBObject ("_id", new ObjectId("531f28101ad8f9ef25000001"));

      BasicDBObject  obj=(BasicDBObject) db.getCollection("tables").findOne(idObj);

      MappingMorphia  mapping=morphia.fromDBObject(MappingMorphia.class,obj);                  
  }
}
```

After execution, the code generates this exception:

> com.google.code.morphia.mapping.MappingException: Trying to map to an unmapped class: MappingMorphia
>
> com.google.code.morphia.Morphia.fromDBObject(Morphia.java:123)
>
> com.google.code.morphia.Morphia.fromDBObject(Morphia.java:118)
>
> TestCon.doGet(TestCon.java:37)
>
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
>
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
>
> org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:33)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using fromDBObject() and not a query?

`datastore.get(MappingMorphia.class, new ObjectId("531f28101ad8f9ef25000001"))`

If you don't explicitly call morphia.map(MappingMorphia.class) your code will never work because morphia doesn't know what that class is.  If you call get(), morphia will recognize that it doesn't know that class and lazy map it before running the query.

But seriously, you should never, ever be calling fromDBObject() manually.  If you do, you likely have a really broken design.

Comment: plz can you give me more explication

Comment: explanation about ... ?